# Elasticsearch + Docker: restoring a backup of the Docker volume is not restoring the ES indexes, why?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have a project with several containers, where one of these containers is an Elasticsearch instance. For reasons that are not essential to the problem, I want to be able to backup the ES data (indexes, mappings, etc).

I know that one way to do so is using *elasticdump*, but one solution that **did not work** for me, and **I want to know why**, is to make a backup of the Docker volume following this reference: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

Summarizing, if I create a backup of the ES volume (btw, I'm working with external volumes):

```
docker run --rm -v {volume_to_backup}:/data -v /path/in/host:/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /data
```

And then restore that backup in a new volume:

```
docker run --rm -v {volume_to_restore_to}:/data -v /path/in/host:/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /data && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --strip 1"
```

And if I try to use that new volume with my Elasticsearch instance by changing the external volume used in my `docker-compose.yml` file, I see that it just doesn't work. Elasticsearch is not finding the indexes.

*Does anybody know why?*

---

The dir structure after restore is:

```
root@ec756fa98ae1:/usr/share/elasticsearch# ls
LICENSE.txt  NOTICE.txt  README.asciidoc  bin  config  data  jdk  lib  logs  modules  plugins
```

And the dir tree within the `data` dir in the container (only directories listed, it's huge otherwise) seems to have proper data:

```
      1 data
      2 `-- nodes
      3     `-- 0
      4         |-- _state
      5         |-- indices
      6         |   |-- -6AbLqXqSBieqIE3bAqK5A
      7         |   |   |-- 0
      8         |   |   |   |-- _state
      9         |   |   |   |-- index
     10         |   |   |   `-- translog
     11         |   |   `-- _state
     12         |   |-- -ni70WZpT1ar4tH6NO_MbA
     13         |   |   |-- 0
     14         |   |   |   |-- _state
     15         |   |   |   |-- index
     16         |   |   |   `-- translog
     17         |   |   `-- _state
     18       ..... many more index directories .....
     19         `-- snapshot_cache
     20 
     21 851 directories
```

Comment: Are the `elasticsearch.yml` configurations in both containers strictly identical (cluster name, etc)? Also, can you show the folder structure of the target volume where you untared the backup?

Comment: @Val I don't have any `elasticsearch.yml` config file, maybe my `docker-compose.yml` is containing all elasticsearch configurations? But in any case, the configurations should be the same because it's literally the same elasticsearch container, just changing which external volume it uses.

EDIT: I found `elasticsearch.yml` within the dir `config` inside the container, it contains only two lines: 1. cluster.name: "docker-cluster" ; 2. network.host: 0.0.0.0

Comment: @Val regarding your second point, I can share the folder structure but it's *huge*, anything in particular? In the meantime I'll share the dir content of the `data` dir in the container.

Comment: Ok thanks for the dir tree, exactly what I was looking for. Can you also paste the container log output from when the container is starting please?

Comment: @Val I tried to reproduce the error just now and I couldn't. And what's worse (better?) the restored volume is working fine with ES now, so it seems I just made some silly mistake the first few times I tried this and now I'm doing it correctly and it works. Sorry to have wasted your time, thanks for your attention, I'll close this question now.

Comment: No time wasted, glad it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

I was clearly making some silly mistake the first few times I tried to restore my ES data by restoring the container volume as specified in the question. I was getting an error for indexes not found, but after doing it again to answer to comments in the question, I got it working.

So, in short, the method works fine and seems to be a valid way to backing up and restoring ES data when running ES in a Docker container.